# How to download Application source files from Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I deployed my Java application about 2-3 months ago on GAE, I don't have the application source code now. I want to make some changes to my application. Is there anyway to download my application sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application):

> You can download an application by running appcfg.sh with the download_app action in the Java SDK command line tool:

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

> This command downloads your compiled application in the WAR that you uploaded most recently.